# Blank Firefox window with error message in eclipse in Selenium webdriver(JAVA)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Firefox version 46.
  Selenium version:2.53.0
  Codes in Eclipse:
  package eezar_test;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class test_sample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("www.gmail.com");

}

}
```

Error Generated in Eclipse:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   Target URL www.gmail.com is not well-formed. Command duration or
>   timeout: 620 milliseconds Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision:
>   '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40' System info: host: 'admin-PC',
>   ip: '192.168.0.102', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64',
>   os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_91' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   databaseEnabled=true, version=46.0.1, platform=WINDOWS,
>   nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox,
>   takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   14d90792-c7c9-4828-a2d2-0de6707c86c5  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:316)
>     at eezar_test.test_sample.main(test_sample.java:15) Caused by:
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Target URL www.gmail.com is
>   not well-formed. Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b',
>   time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40' System info: host: 'admin-PC', ip:
>   '192.168.0.102', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_91' Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>     at .FirefoxDriver.prototype.get(file:///C:/Users/Monojit/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3216851504162366486webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10636)
>     at .DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/Monojit/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3216851504162366486webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
>     at .DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/Monojit/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3216851504162366486webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
>     at .DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/Monojit/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3216851504162366486webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the protocol to your get method.

```
driver.get("http://gmail.com");
```

Comment: That was silly. I have just started using Selenium. Hope you understand that. Thanks a lot by the way.